# Wordpress subdomain on localhost

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, localhost

Because of the requirement of a site in the network called 'blog', I had to use sub-domains instead of subfolders. WordPress doesn't allow a subfolder called 'blog'.

Anyway, so I added these changes in my hosts file:

- 127.0.0.1 site1.localhost
- 127.0.0.1 site2.localhost
- 127.0.0.1 blog.localhost

Then I went to my httpd.conf file and added the setup for each individual subdomains for localhost:

For site 1:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias site1.localhost
    DocumentRoot "..\htdocs\wordpress\site1"
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html index.htm index.shtml
</VirtualHost>
```

and so on for site2 and blog. I am a little unsure about using * there. I think something else goes there. :/

I went on to activate multisite in my wp-config file as:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

But, at the end of the process I'm getting this message:

> Because you are using localhost, the sites in your WordPress network must use sub-directories. Consider using localhost.localdomain if you wish to use sub-domains.

What must I do to get subdomains then?

Would really appreciate your help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `*` is a wildcard.  Basically, you're telling Apache to listen to port 80 on all IPs pointed at the server.  For localhost, no big deal.  But if you had multiple IPs pointing at a host, you'd substitute the IP for the `*` in the `VirtualHost` declaration.

IE:

```
NameVirtualHost 123.4.5.6:80
<VirtualHost 123.4.5.6:80>
    ...
```

Now on to the error message.  Basically, WordPress sees "localhost" and assumes you're testing locally and won't be setting up subdomains.  My recommendation would be to use a different host and set up your system to act appropriately (Basically, `localhost` can't have subdomains unless you set up up in a specific way to begin with).

So instead, use `site1.local`, `site2.local`, `blog.local` and so on.  Then change your hosts file and httpd.conf file the same (substitute `local` everywhere you used `localhost`).

Comment: Does this mean I have to reinstall Wordpress to align with my new 'local'?

If I'm not mistaken, I change my hosts file to read local and then add the site1.local etc. in the conf file. Is this correct?

Or how about this as an alternative? I use sub-folders and use the word 'blogs' instead of 'blog' but while transferring the site to a web host, I use subdomains where I get to use 'blog' again. Would this work?

Comment: Try to avoid switching between subdomains and subfolders.  It takes a lot of work to fully switch WP to use one or the other, so pick one and stick with it.